# Get ALL sql queries executed in the last several hours in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need a way to collect all queries executed in Oracle DB (Oracle Database 11g) in the last several hours regardless of how fast the queries are (this will be used to calculate sql coverage after running tests against my application that has several points where queries are executed).

I cannot use tables like V$SQL since there's no guarantee that a query will remain there long enough. It seems I could use DBA_HIST_SQLTEXT but I didn't find a way to filter out queries executed before current test run.

So my question is: what table could I use to get absolutely all queries executed in the given period of time (up to 2 hours) and what DB configuration should I adjust to reach my goal?

Comment: You probably can't.  Oracle isn't going to store a history of every `select` query that has ever been issued.  I suppose you could enable tracing across all sessions at the beginning of the time period and then parse the trace files later.  That would make the database extremely slow, though, and the trace files that get generated would be large and unwieldy.  It would seem vastly easier, particularly since this is a testing effort, to instrument your code to record that information.

Comment: My starting point with this type of requirement is to look at AWR to figure out what data is available, and then construct my own queries to match my needs if AWR does not suffice.  In your case I would look at running snapshots every hour, then running your report for the last seven hours. I think the AWR stuff within Oracle is going to be the most accurate means. Also look at tables in this list: "SELECT * from dict where table_name like 'DBA_HIST%' or table_name like 'V$%HIST%'". The trickiest thing is understanding that the stats in these tables are cumulative.

Comment: Do you actually need the SQL statement or would the type of statement that was run, by whom, against which objects, etc. be enough? The latter is available w/ standard logging (though not the SQL statement itself).

Comment: I need the query itself since I need to learn which queries out of all queries coded in the application are executed during the test.

Comment: Set up a fine grained auditing. Refer to the `dbms_fga` package for info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with what [Justin Cave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10397/justin-cave) suggested and instrumented Oracle JDBC driver to collect every executed query in a Set and them dump them all into a file after running the tests.

Answer (score 1):

> "I need the query itself since I need to learn which queries out of all queries coded in the application are executed during the test"

The simplest way of capturing all the queries executed would be to enable Fine Grained Audit on all your database tables.  You could use the data dictionary to generate policies on every application table.

Note that even when writing to an OS file such a number of policies would generate a high impact on the database, and will increase the length of time it takes to run the tests.  Therefore you should only use these policies to assess your test coverage, and disable them for other test runs.

[Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/auditing.htm#DBSEG525).